# how to find service calling in spring framwork JAVA?

Tags: java, spring

I have process belows :

[image]

Service1,Service2,Service3 call method a() of DAO together.

How to find service calling in inside method a()?

Comment: Why do you want to know the caller in the dao? What is the usecase for that.

Comment: i want to know the caller in the dao. because in method a() as example if service1 i will execute action1 else service2 i will execute action2 ...

Comment: Bad design in the first place, just call the method from the desired service... You don't want to introduce a dependency from the service layer to the dao layer, you then introduce a cyclic dependency which imho you shouldn't want nor need. Let the caller decide himself which method he needs to call (or create multiple different implementation of the interface and inject the proper one into the desired service).

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea, because you will introduce a coupling from DAO to service. Since service already has a dependency to the DAO, it will introduce a cycle. Instead try to work with different implementations of that DAO and inject the correct instance with qualifiers or write at least separate methods which then are called from the services.

Comment: Actually just a service call a DAO. But i wonder if mutil service call a DAO . how we know service calling ?

Comment: We don't know, because it's not necessary in a well designed system.

Comment: that's right . "the caller decide himself which method he needs to call" . method is don't need to who is calling. Thanks dunni and @M. Deinum